# zend session and zend Auth in zend 2.2.4

Tags: zend-framework

i have just logged in a user in zend framework 2.2.4 and stored the whole data row in storage.This is within the switch case after a successful login
                       case Result::SUCCESS:

```
                                             $storage=$auth->getStorage();
                                             $storage->write($authAdapter->getResultRowObject(null,'usr_password'));

                                             $time=1209600;
                                             if($data['Remember_Me'])
                                             {
                                                 $sessionManager=new \Zend\Session\SessionManager();
                                                 $sessionManager->rememberMe($time);

                                             }
                                            break;
```

how do i read the data from storage and pass it to a view.Please help.thanks in advance

Comment: or is there a way to check if a user is logged in before he/she can perfom a particular action..?

Comment: got it.use hasIdentity and getIdentity.

Answer (score 0):

**in the controller**

```
if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity())
{
      $storage = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
      $this->view->storage= $storage;
}
```

**in the view**

```
<?php echo $this->escape($this->storage->username); ?>
```